# create backup on mysql master-slave

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.7, master-slave-replication

I have MySQL version 5.7 with a master-slave configuration. but I'm confused to make a backup cron. Is there a way to do a backup while remaining safe to master-slave? I heard that using mysqldump is too risky

Comment: `mysqldump` works just fine if you use it on a cold (i.e. not running) database or even a hot one (running) using `--single-transaction`. The solution of choice for backups on MySQL is [Percona's XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup). Obviously, a backup will cause performance issues - the entire database has to be copied in consistent state for the time of the backup. That's why you have a slave - you backup the slave with no performance problems on the master. The slave then catches up. No hot backups possible with MyISAM, hence replication.

Comment: I tried that, but it made my slave database locked. and to reset the replication after being locked is a bit difficult because of the large data

Comment: XtraBackup has incremental backup - can you  use that and then do a full backup on Sat. night - Sun. morning or other suitable window? There's also [Mariabackup](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariabackup/) - a fork of XtraBackup. Don't know much about it, but it might be worth a look? MariaDB has the original architect of MySQL (Monty Widenius) & many other MySQL experts. HTH.

Comment: Another approach to backing up a slave is to top mysqld, and copy the disk drive.  (That's also a way to create another slave.)